# Building an argument list from a C string

Tags: c, linux

I don't like re-inventing the wheel.

Is there a standard or Linux specific function to transform a C style string (char*)
to a char** style array of strings format like that passed into main?

i.e. given:

```
const char* s = "-n file -m -o output"
```

Dynamically convert that to what would be:

```
char** args = { "-n", "file", "-m", "-o", "output", 0 };
```

A function like:

```
char** build_arg_array(const char* cmd_line);
```

EDIT:
Thanks for the responses.  Looks like there isn't a one step function that does the above already.

Comment: What do you mean "convert"? One is a char pointer, the other is an array of char pointers.

Comment: Brian. I'm not talking about a typecast! The subject says "BUILD". Sorry I should use the word "tranform" or "build" in the content.  I've now altered the question.  You should really try to understand the question before just happily hitting the downvote.

Comment: Are you looking for something that splits a string by whitespace? Or are you looking for a full parser that follows the shell rules for quoting and escaping and whatnot?

Comment: You are looking for something that converts a string to arguments for one of execl() family?

Comment: @MattH - and you shouldn't assume someone downvoted you when they were just trying to get you to clarify your question (presumably to keep it from being downvoted). Because you know what ASSumptions do, right?

Comment: How do you wish to divide the memory addresses of the original `char*` to store in your array of char pointers `char**`?  Your question is rather ambiguous.

Comment: Splitting by white space is fine.  I believe there must be something like this in existence already.  After all, whatever takes the command line and passes it to main is doing it.  Otherwise I'll have to roll my own.

Comment: Brian, now that my question is quite clear (I hope) perhaps you should remove your downvote?

Comment: strtok will split strings for you (in a loop).

Comment: @Mouse Food.  I know that.  I'm talking about building the entire char** in one step.  Really, quite disappointed at the responses here.   A simple, "No, there is no exposed standard function to do this" would suffice.

Comment: @Matt H No, there is no exposed standard function to do this.  But stop being defensive.  Most queries are because there is some genuine interest in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Unix-like systems, it is the shell that does the argument parsing. So your shell will apply all of its argument splitting, wildcard expansion, quoting, and redirection logic, generate the array of arguments, fork a new process, and call [`execve`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/exec.html) (or one of the other `exec` variants) with the results of its parsing.

So no, there isn't a standard library call to parse arguments the way that the shell does, as that logic is implemented in the shell, not in the standard library. You can call [`system`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/system.html) or [`popen`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/popen.html), which are wrappers around [`fork`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/fork.html) and `exec` to run a shell command with a string, or you could call out to the shell yourself using `fork` and `exec`.

Of course, then you have all of the problems of passing potentially untrusted input to a shell, and you would have to devise a way of communicating the results back to your parent process, perhaps using `popen` to open a pipe to read the results of the command you launch, which prints null-delimited arguments to standard out.

Other than that, if you don't want to spawn a new process and just want to parse the arguments within your program, you will have to implement your own parser.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer.  This is what I was after.  Actually I'm not forking a process, it's an internal function inside an open source library that I'm utilizing that expects arguments in this form.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't too hard:

```
char **split(char *input, char splitChar, int *outCount)
{
    int inputLen = (int) strlen(input);
    int numberOfArguments = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < inputLen; i++)
    {
        if (input[i] == splitChar)
            numberOfArguments++;
    }

    *outCount = numberOfArguments;
    char **output = malloc(sizeof(char *) * numberOfArguments);

    int startOfArg = 0; 
    int outputIndex = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < inputLen; i++)
    {
        if (input[i] == splitChar)
        {
            int argLen = i - startOfArg;
            output[outputIndex] = malloc(sizeof(char) * argLen + 1);
            strncpy(output[outputIndex], input + startOfArg, argLen);
            output[outputIndex][argLen] = 0;     

            startOfArg = i + 1;
            outputIndex++;
        }
    }

    // append the last argument
    int argLen = inputLen - startOfArg;
    output[outputIndex] = malloc(sizeof(char) * argLen + 1);
    strncpy(output[outputIndex], input + startOfArg, argLen);
    output[outputIndex][argLen] = 0;

    return output;
}
```

Comment: Actually, it's quite a bit harder than this if you want to do this right; i.e., if you'd properly check for errors, avoiding memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

Just re-invent the wheel.

If I understand your question correctly you want to implement something like the `split()` function in Python, Perl and other language.  I know of no such thing in C, but so you might as well write one yourself.

Comment: Is using `strtok(string, " \t")` re-inventing the wheel?

Answer (score 0):

The gtk glib library can be considered something of a standard for C, and it has the function you are looking for (or very close): g_strsplit
http://www.gtk.org/api/2.6/glib/glib-String-Utility-Functions.html#g-strsplit